# Question about 'self.assertIn' & 'driver.title'

Tags: selenium2, python

I researched this as much as I could on my own but came to no clear conclusion to my question. I've been teaching myself automation testing via Python + Selenium, I'm as new or n00b as it gets so bare with me. I've come across this line in some of my tutorials:

`self.assertIn` but more like this, `self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)` and I've also seen it like this (simple use, not in unittest) `assert "Python" in driver.title`

... so far I've been able to grasp the tutorials, at least where my progress has taken me but I do not understand the function of this `driver.title`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It is getting the title of the web page and seeing if it has Python in it.

How much HTML do you know?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Phil. I know a bit of HTML, actually although python and selenium are very new to me. Does the title in the test have to match word-for-word the title in the browser? Thank you for your input.

Comment: Also, what is the best place to find a complete or extensive guide to syntax. I've read through these links [link](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) and [link](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/index.html) but they just don't seem to have a complete library to read through, or maybe it's just my initial ignorance into this venture.

Comment: See this thread for different ways of using the title - contains or exact - http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7887/question-about-the-selenium-gettitle-method

Comment: Did you look here - and links from here - for basic webdriver info? http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Comment: Thank you again, Phil. I guess it's just eagerness on my part. Wanting to take it all in. I forgot that the journey is just as important as the end.